# d3 - x axis on time with 30 mins interval

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have created a `x-axis` using the `d3.svg.axis()`.

I've oriented it to `bottom` but it's still appearing on top of the svg. And even the `x-axis` labels are not visible.

**JS :**

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width])

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
                 .call(xAxis);
```

**Data :**

```
time,count
00:12,1
00:45,1
01:14,1
01:30,1
01:57,1
02:21,1
02:44,1
02:50,1
03:13,1
03:41,1
03:59,1
04:10,1
04:23,1
04:45,1
04:59,1
05:01,1
05:17,1
05:48,1
06:00,1
06:11,1
06:23,1
06:31,1
06:47,1
07:12,1
07:29,1
07:41,1
07:58,1
```

**Entire Code :**

```
    var height = 200;
var width = 1000;
var count = 50, padding = 11;

var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width])

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

var svgContainer = d3.select(".spectrum")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("class", "g")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)

function movein() {
    d3.selectAll("line")
        .attr("stroke", "#555")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .attr("y1", 90)
        .attr("y2", 25)

    d3.select(this)
        .attr("y1", 90)
        .attr("y2", 25)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("y1", 115)
        .attr("y2", 0)
        .attr("stroke", "#555")

    var xvalue = d3.select(this)
                    .attr('x1')

    var yvalue = d3.select(this)
                    .attr('y1')

    d3.select('.g')
        .append('text')
        .attr('x', +xvalue - 20)
        .attr('y', +yvalue + 40)
        .text('TEXT')
}

function moveout() {
    d3.selectAll("line")
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("stroke", "#555")
        .attr("y1", 90)
        .attr("y2", 25)

    d3.selectAll('text').remove();
}

var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
                          .call(xAxis);

// for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    d3.csv("data2.csv", function(data) {
    var line = svgContainer.selectAll("line")
                        .data(data)
                        .enter()
                        .append("line")
                        .attr("x1", function(d,i){return padding*i})
                        .attr("x2", function(d,i){return padding*i})
                        .attr("y1", 90)
                        .attr("y2", 25)
                        .attr("stroke", "#555")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 10)
                        .on("mouseover", movein)
                        .on("mouseout", moveout)
    })
```

Here I wish to configure the interval of times with 30 mins.

Help will be very much thankful.

Comment: The orientation argument refers to where the ticks appear with respect to the axis line (i.e. in your case below it). This does not affect where the axis appears with respect to the graph at all. You need to move it the position you want it to be at yourself.

Comment: How will it move to the bottom then? And all the times intervals doesn't appear in the `x-axis`. Only 1 unit is visible at the beginning and there's nothing after that.

Comment: I managed to move to bottom. But it's not visible.

Comment: You also need to parse the dates and set a domain on your x scale.

Comment: I don't have `date` in the data. Only `time` I have in the data.

Comment: You need to parse those into Javascript `Date` objects in order to be able to use a time scale.

Comment: I don't have any clue on what you're saying. I'll google it and give it a try.